# Multiple html5 canvas elements: performance issue?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Regardless of the javascript, is there a performance problem when adding multiple html5 canvas elements for the purpose of displaying canvas made icon? I mean is there a difference performancewise between a div and canvas sematic element?

I am trying to step away from images, svg and even fontawesome, thats why im asking.

Comment: I would suggest to genereate all resources with one canvas, save it as blob for example, and then use common html elements to display it (like img or CSS background-img).

Comment: @EntityBlack can you show an example of how that works? Im familiar with css backgrounds but not with canvas.

Comment: @Asperger you can save the contents of a canvas as a `data:` URL and then make that the `src` of an image tag, or the background URL of a CSS style.

Comment: @Alnitak Oh I see! Isnt that a bit intensive and messy looking? Im thinking that might introduce other problems.

Comment: "Regardless of the javascript" canvas element is just an empty `<img>` tag. Now with regard to javascript, whatever solution you do use to pass its bitmap to an `<img>` tag or any CSS property will just be more performance intensive than simple redraws of the canvas element.

Comment: @Asperger there is no basis in fact that I know of for the two assertions in the answer that you've accepted.  I have previously written a very substantial web-UI with large dynamic graphs using HTML5 canvas and performance was no concern at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes,

Performance depends on the total area of all canvases, try to keep it( total area of canvas) small.

If you are planning to use canvas then try to use clipping option , it will increase performance.

Comment: What do you say about Entity Blacks tip?

Comment: Yes, performance decreases with the total of all elements on a page.  This is a non-answer, AFAICS.

Comment: Entity Blacks is correct, but then also you have to take care of active drawing areas, while you will draw multiple time on a single canvas it will take time to draw common areas, and if opacity is there the drawing till will increase also.

Comment: Have you any reference for this ? In my mind, "Regardless of the javascript" Canvas element is just like an `<img>` element. The document's repaint will just be the same.

Comment: @Kaiido *both* of the assertions in this answer need references.

Comment: @Alnitak completely agreed, clipping will just create more calculations to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the request, I have this short code:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 250;
canvas.height = 80;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 80);
//draw a red box
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.font = "30px Tahoma";
ctx.fillText("Hello World", 45, 50);


var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById("img-data").innerHTML = dataURL;
document.getElementById("canvas-mirror").src = dataURL;
```

```html
<div id="img-data"></div>
<img id="canvas-mirror"></div>
```

In short,

1. Create canvas element with javascript. You don't have to include it into html, why would you? This way it might be a little bit faster.
2. Use canvas.getContext 2d, WebGL or whatever you want to do. This is essential, once you choose method, you shouldnt change it! (Dont use it twice on same canvas.)
3. Draw anything you want.
4. Get data from canvas back. Now the most known way is to use "high level" method toDataUrl. This is good and easy to do. But in case of more complicated application, you might choose also different methods, for example webgl has [readPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.12) which is faster, like really fast, you get smaller data and you can also use scissors before, but it is also much harder to code.
5. Use data for image. In case of base64 it is valid param for img src property. WebGL readPixels must be transformed first. It might be binary blob or base64.

Comment: I know OP's clearly stated "Regardless of the javascript", but what you are doing with javascript here is like a thousand repaint of a canvas element. Moreover, converting to a dataURI version will make the whole image to state in the browser's memory, just beside the canvas element until GC kicks in.

Comment: @Kaiido This is just the most simple example and I stated this in the answer. I don't see any "thousand repaint" of canvas element, I see 2. 
This is true, dataURI will put image in browsers memory, but OP stated he wants to use it for icons, which I as small pcis with only few colors. DataURI was designed for such a thing. Also I cleary stated blob file can be used instead. 
Sure, I expect someone will use his brain before he implements it for real usage.

Comment: the paintings I am talking about are the ones that the browser does of any elements in the page, which is the only performance issue if we don't look at js side. The toDataURL method in it self is kinda slow, creating an img element and setting its src also has a cost.